# Has asyncio been removed from redis-py?

Tags: python-3.x, redis, fastapi, redis-py, aioredis

I'm currently working on setting up `Redis` with `FastAPI`. This is my first time using `redis` and in my attempt to find out whether it was possible to use `redis` asynchronously, I stumbled upon [aioredis-py](https://github.com/aio-libs/aioredis-py).

According to their documentation:

[image]

However, my IDE is currently throwing the following error:

[image]

This is basically telling me that `asyncio` cannot be found in `redis`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue? What's the best to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem this issue is unique to [folks who may be using PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53965/redis-py-stub-doesnt-know-about-asyncio-module-in-reds-42-inclusion-of-aioredis).

The issue pertains to a bug in typeshed and their redis stub generators. A viable workaround can be found [HERE](https://github.com/redis/redis-py/issues/2249#issuecomment-1269864121).